How to store the values of each array into a promisechain using forEach javascript?
i am new to javascript and i am trying to loop through each array of objects and execute a function on each object. this function returns a promise which i need to return to the main function calling this.
below is the code,
createTypes({types: [type1, type2, type3]}, false).as('createdTypes');

const createTypes = ({ count =1, types = new Array(count).fill(),}, skip = true) => {
    let promiseChain;
    types.forEach(type => {
        if (!skip) {
            promiseChain = cy.createType(type, false);
        } else {
            promiseChain = cy.createType(type);
        }
    }
    return promiseChain;
}

in the above code, i am executing createType method on each type. if skip is false then i want to execute createType with type and false. if skip is true i want to execute createType with type alone. createType method returns a promise.
so for each type create a promise is returned and i want to store all the promises in one variable (array of objects) and return it to calling function.
in the above code only the promise from last executed type is saved.
how can i store all the promises in one. could someone help me with this. thanks

Seems overcomplicated, you don't need a separate function for that if you don't reuse it, just make in place, omit skip if not needed:
const promise = Promise.all([type1, type2, type3].map(type => cy.createType(type, false /* skip value here */)));


how are we covering the situation when we also pass only type and no skip value

@Harika, just don't provide the skip argument, omit it
